# Type error in matplotlib renderer when saving pcolormesh figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, conda

I've recently changed one of my plotting scripts to use pcolormesh instead of contourf. It's part of a script that loops over several netCDF datasets to create a couple of maps at different timesteps and, in the problematic part, cross-sections of some variables at a specific location over time. The code line used to be:

```
im = ax.contourf(X,Y,np.transpose(data),*args,**kwargs)
```

where X (time, converted to float64 seconds) and Y (height, also float64) are a meshgrid and data is the corresponding slice of the netcdf dataset (float32). I replaced it with

```
im = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,np.transpose(data),shading='gouraud',*args,**kwargs)
```

as it happened that the plot style works better for the data. The kwargs are a colorbar and the colorbar limits, nothing out of the ordinary.

It worked fine on my small test case that I had on my local (Windows) machine using spyder, however when I try to use it on the (Linux) Server from the command line, it suddenly gives me the following error message when I'm trying to save the plot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(redacted)/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    dataset.make_plots()
  File "(redacted)/plotDataset.py", line 75, in make_plots
    self._crossecPlot(data, variable, crossec)
  File "(redacted)/plotDataset.py", line 196, in _crossecPlot
    plt.savefig(self.settings['output_path']+'/'+filename+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1023, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3343, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qtagg.py", line 75, in print_figure
    super().print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2366, in print_figure
    result = print_method(
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2232, in <lambda>
    print_method = functools.wraps(meth)(lambda *args, **kwargs: meth(
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 509, in print_png
    self._print_pil(filename_or_obj, "png", pil_kwargs, metadata)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 457, in _print_pil
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 400, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3140, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 3064, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "(redacted)/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 2095, in draw
    renderer.draw_gouraud_triangles(
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I've already tried using the default (nearest) shading type instead of Gouraud triangles, which gave me the same error except that it's in `renderer.draw_quad_mesh`, and I've used the shared anaconda installation before installing miniconda with the hope that it was something that got fixed in an update.

What is suprising to me, when i use `im = ax.pcolormesh(lons,lats,values,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),*args, **kwargs)` in a different plot type (which uses a different slice of the same data and cartopy), the error doesn't occur. All in all though, I have no idea where the `float128` type is coming from, and why it wouldn't convert to a `float64` (since it's only for plotting, i would think that the lost precision shouldn't be much of an issue).

Comment: Do you have a minimum reproducible example for us to play with?

Comment: It's hard to know what is happening - apparently something in your toolchain upcast to float128 - Matplotlib fails on that because it's not well defined on all systems.  You can just cast it yourself before passing to Matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be as Jody Klomak said - if I explicitly cast X, Y, and the data to float64 by adding `.astype('float64')`, it works. I still didn't figure out why it happened in the first place, but I'm happy that it works now.

Comment: Just FYI, it is customary to give a commenter a chance to provide the answer when their comment (essentially) answers your question.

Comment: ah, how do i do that? just comment that it worked and wait? or is there some button i can use to promote the comment to an answer?

Comment: Yeah, just a comment back to their comment, along the lines of "Thanks this was really helpful, if you submit this as an answer I will accept it." If they don't get back to you within a couple days, you can just carry on.